# Java Swing Updates

Tags: java, swing, class, sockets, tcp

So this is in reference to my previous questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22619323/java-menubar-action-to-a-class) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22646567/java-using-mainwindow-functions). Basically the problem I am having is the program goes into the `Server` class and stays there because there is a while look in the server code that essentially is continuously listening to the port for any response from the client; this makes the Main window completely unclickable since the program is not in the `MainWindow` class.

But really what I want it to do is setup the connection and then go back to `MainWindow` so the on-screen buttons are clickable. Or, as suggested by one poster, I could pass the MainWindow object by reference to the Server (which I have already done) and then use `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()` but I'm not really looking to *update* the GUI. I'm looking to give control back to the GUI so the user can click buttons and such.

When it goes back to `MainWindow`, I still need the connection to stay alive so the client can send things and I can receive it and display the received content on the screen for the user to control.

Comment: And what's wrong with using a [`SwingWorker`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) for talking with the server?

Comment: @MadProgrammer So would I use SwingWorker from the `MainWindow` class so that the connection can be setup separetly? I'm not quite sure how SwingWorker works...even after reading the docs...

Comment: @MadProgrammer so if I am understanding this correctly, it seems I will setup an object like so: `SwingWorker worker = new SwingWorker...` with the functions that need to be executed inside this worker object. However, the Server is an entire class so how will I encapsulate that into the SwingWorker object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, you could use a `SwingWorker` to perform actions in the background, off the Event Dispatching Thread, which will allow you application to continue working...

```
SwingWorker<Server , Object> worker = new SwingWorker<Server , Object>() {
    @Override
    protected ServerdoInBackground() throws Exception {
        Server server = new Server();
        //...
        // Use publish(...) to send information
        // back the EDT via the process method...
        return server;
    }

    @Override
    protected void done() {
        try {
            Server server = get();
        } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void process(List<Object> chunks) {
        // You can safly update the UI from here, maybe
        // with some messages??
    }

};
worker.execute();
```

Basically, this creates a new `Server` object in the `doInBackground` method, does what ever else it needs to do that might otherwise block the EDT and exits by returning the `server` instance.

You can use `done` if you want to be notified when the `doInBackground` method completes and either get the result of the method, or if it threw an exception, handle the exeption.

The `publish`/`process` methods can be used to send information back to the EDT, which could be used to update the state of the UI...or not...

Now, if you already have a reference to the server, may consider creating a custom `SwingWorker` to which you pass the reference of the `Server` to...

```
Server server = ...;
ConnectionWorker worker = new ConnectionWorker(server);
worker.execute();

//...

public class ConnectionWorker extends SwingWorker<Object, Object> {

    private Server server;
    public ConnectionWorker(Server server) {
        this.server;
    }

    @Override
    protected ServerdoInBackground() throws Exception {
        server.doStuff(); //...
        return ...;
    }

}
```

Take a look at [`SwingWorker`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) more details